# Why this state is stuck only in this function even after it gets changed? - NextJS 13.3.0 / React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

I have a button to show a modal creating using a `dialog` html element, this button is stored in a state (`thingsToRender`) in consquence to a condition (in this case, I simulated the condition in a `useEffect` hook), and then if `someCondition` is true, the contents in `thingsToRender` are rendered. The problems is that `checkboxState` seems always to be `true` in `handleRevealButtonClick` even if its actual value is changed to `false` in `handleCheckboxChange` after the checkbox that asks if the modal must not be shown again is checked.

Seems that the problems is in storing the `button` with the function `handleRevealButtonClick` in the state `thingsToRender`, but I didn't find a solution that satifies my requirements, since I need that button to be rendered that way beacuse is contained in a grid item in the real example. So how can I make that button to not get stucked in the previous state of `checkboxState`?

Here's the minimal reproducible example:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'

function Test() 
{
    const [checkboxState, setCheckboxState] = useState(true);
    const [someCondition, setSomeCondition] = useState(false);
    const [thingsToRender, setThingsTorRender] = useState(<h1>Something</h1>);

    const dialogRef = useRef(null);
    const checkboxRef = useRef(null);

    const handleCheckboxChange = () =>
    {
        const checkbox = checkboxRef.current;

        if(checkbox.checked)
        {
            setCheckboxState(false)
        }
        else
        {
            setCheckboxState(true);
        }
    }

    const handleRevealButtonClick = () =>
    {
        if(checkboxState)
        {
            const dialog = dialogRef.current;
            dialog.showModal();
        }
    }

    const handleCloseButtonClick = () =>
    {
        const dialog = dialogRef.current;
        dialog.close();
    }

    useEffect(() =>
    {
        // Problem seems to be here
        setThingsTorRender(<button onClick={handleRevealButtonClick}>Reveal modal</button>)
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            <dialog ref={dialogRef}>
                <div>
                    <input type="checkbox" ref={checkboxRef} onChange={handleCheckboxChange}/> 
                    <label>Not reveal again?</label>
                </div>
                
                <button onClick={handleCloseButtonClick}>Close</button>
            </dialog>

            {someCondition === true ? <h1>Some stuff</h1> : thingsToRender}
        </div>)
}

export default Test;
```

**EDIT:** In order to clarify why the button needs to be on a state, I'll show this example closer to the real example (notice that `thingsToRender` contain elements of a grid that are defined from firebase documents):

```
    const renderGrid = () =>
    {
        // query from Firebase
        const grid = query.map((document, index) => 
                <React.Fragment key={index}>
                    <div className='grid-item'>{document.data}</div>
                    <div className='grid-item'>{document.data}</div>
                    <div className='grid-item'>
                        <button onClick={handleRevealButtonClick}>Reveal modal</button>
                    </div>
                </React.Fragment>
            )

        setThingsTorRender(grid)
    }

    useEffect(() =>
    {
        renderGrid();
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            {/* dialog */}

            {someCondition === true ? <h1>Some stuff</h1> : <div className='grid-container'> {thingsToRender} </div>}
        </div>)
```

Comment: Can you clarify a little about why your button is being stored in state instead of just being rendered directly in your returned JSX? Not storing it in state will fix this issue.

Comment: Yes, check the last edit. It's beacuse the button is part of an grid element that are defined with firebase document data

Comment: Thanks, you should be able to do `query.map((document, index) =>  <React.Fragment key={index}>...` in place of `thingsToRender` in your JSX. Still doesn't seem like it needs to be a state value.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention there is a refresh button, which calls `renderGrid` function to refetch the documents, so I use the state to update the data every time it is called to be refreshed

Comment: Seems like your refresh button should be updating a `query` state (the data that you map to create your grid). By updating the `query` state, your component will rerender causing the new grid to be created when it's returned within your JSX

Comment: I see, what you said work. Thanks! If you want you can write an aswer to mark it as solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't store JSX in state (there's usually no need to). Instead, put your JSX into your `return` to avoid putting it into state, and then use state to control `query` so that it rerenders your grid when changed:

```js
<div className='grid-container'>{query.map((doc, index) => 
  <React.Fragment key={index}>
    <div className='grid-item'>{doc.data}</div>
    <div className='grid-item'>{doc.data}</div>
    <div className='grid-item'>
      <button onClick={handleRevealButtonClick}>Reveal modal</button>
    </div>
  </React.Fragment>)
}</div>
```

If you want, you can put the above into its own `Grid` component to make this easier to read as pass `query` as props to it.

---

To understand why your current approach doesn't work you first need to be clear about what happens when your component rerenders. Upon each rerender, your `Test` component is executed again, creating a new scope where your state variables, functions, etc. defined within your `Test` component are recreated again. This means that there are multiple "versions" of the `handleRevealButtonClick` callback function across different renders of your component. Each version of `handleRevealButtonClick` only has knowledge of the state values for that particular render of your component that the  `handleRevealButtonClick` was created in.

Your problem is that the `<button>` you set inside of your `useEffect()` is created once, on the initial mount of your component (due to the empty dependency array). That means that the `onClick` callback that you set of `handleRevealButtonClick` refers to the initial `handleRevealButtonClick` created on the first render which only knows about the value for the `checkbox` state from the initial render of your component and not the new value it may be set to.